# Neomodel: ValueError: Can't install traversal 'source' exists on NodeSet

Tags: python, django, neo4j, neomodel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgBXe.png)

I used django_neomodel to connect the Neo4j graph database. The graph data in Neo4j database is above which is the relationships between genes.

This is my model for data.

```
class Genes(StructuredNode):
    id = StringProperty()
    name = StringProperty()
    source = Relationship('Genes', 'Interaction')
    target = Relationship('Genes', 'Interaction')
```

When I run `len(Genes.nodes)` in python shell, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "G:\software\anaconda\envs\flybase\lib\site-packages\neomodel\util.py", line 344, in __get__
    return self.getter(type)
  File "G:\software\anaconda\envs\flybase\lib\site-packages\neomodel\core.py", line 266, in nodes
    return NodeSet(cls)
  File "G:\software\anaconda\envs\flybase\lib\site-packages\neomodel\match.py", line 581, in __init__
    install_traversals(self.source_class, self)
  File "G:\software\anaconda\envs\flybase\lib\site-packages\neomodel\match.py", line 172, in install_traversals
    raise ValueError("Can't install traversal '{0}' exists on NodeSet".format(key))
ValueError: Can't install traversal 'source' exists on NodeSet
```

Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

`source` is just a [reserved attribute of a NodeSet in neomodel](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/blob/481e2bbe8b153e78198de9d69260958d8a883050/neomodel/match.py#L570-L578).

Use a different name for your Relationship instance.